# Sum of variables converging in law and variables converging in probability converges in law

Tags: probability, random-variables

I know that, in general, convergence in law isn’t preserved under summation. So if I have two sequences of rv $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converging in law to $X$ and $Y$, their sum needn’t converge to $X+Y$. However, I think that if one of them converges in probabilty, this should be true. Do you have any hints on how to prove this?

Comment: As you can see in the answer of Kavi it is not even true if one of them is constant (hence convergent almost surely). Another point is that the conditions on $X_n$ and $Y_n$ do not require that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are defined on the same probability space. In that case $X_n+Y_n$ is not properly defined.

Comment: Oh, you are right! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true. Let $X$ have standard normal distribution. $X_n=X$ for all $n$ and $Y_n =-X$ for all $n$. Then $Y_n \to X$ in distribution, $X_n \to X$ in probability but $0=X_n+Y_n$ does not converge to $2X$ in distribution.

Comment: Absolutely right. But then: what is needed for the limit of the sum to converge (in distribution) to the sum of the limits?

Comment: I mean, I need something like this because I want to apply the central limit theorem, but I have a sort of “tail” that converges to 0. It converges in all senses, I think (almost everywhere and L1, too). Maybe if one of the two sequences converge to 0, something can be said?

Comment: I have no idea what kind of situation you are in. If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ and independent for each $n$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $X_n+Y_n \to X+Y$ in distribution. Does that help?

Comment: Yes! They are indipendent. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I’d have another (probably simple) problem, regarding Markov chains. If you want to check I leave here the link. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271091/verify-markov-property